# Performing requests on behalf of users from a node.js server

Tags: firebase

I am trying to implement a node.js server with firebase as my persistent layer.

Users can log in and get an accessToken that is generated from the custome authentication firebase module.

Then on each future request the clients will give the server their given accessToken and then the server will perform actions by connecting to a the firebase ref as the requesting user.

```
    var ref = new Firebase("https://cexample.firebaseio.com/");
    ref.authWithCustomToken(token, function(error, authData) {
      ref.child("users").child(authData.uid).set({
        data: authData.uid,
        provider: "custom"
      });

    });
```

this approach doesn't work since firebase maintains only once authentication state for a given firebase url.

this means that performing this code:

```
    var ref = new Firebase("https://cexample.firebaseio.com/");
    ref.authWithCustomToken(token1, function(error, authData) {
      ref.child("users").child(authData.uid).set({
        data: authData.uid,
        provider: "custom"
      });

    });

    var ref1 = new Firebase("https://cexample.firebaseio.com/");
    ref1.authWithCustomToken(token2, function(error, authData) {
      ref.child("users").child(authData.uid).set({
        data: authData.uid,
        provider: "custom"
      });

    });
```

will not work. only the second callback, the one of ref1, will be called.

Is there anyway to be able to handle requests to firebase from a node.js server as different users per request?

Answer (score 2):

You could spawn a child process for each separate auth token you want to use, but that would not be very efficient:

```
// server.js
for (var i in users) {
    var user = users[i];
    var token = createTokenForUser(user);
    child_process.spawn("./single-user-worker.js", [token]);
}

// single-user-worker.js
var token = process.argv.pop();
var ref = new Firebase("https://cexample.firebaseio.com/");
ref.authWithCustomToken(token, ...);
```

It would be more efficient to just create a high-privileged token for the server to use for all users:

```
var token = createAdminToken();
var ref = new Firebase("https://cexample.firebaseio.com/");
ref.authWithCustomToken(token, function(error, authData) {
  for (var i in users) {
    var user = users[i];
    ref.child("users").child(user.uid).set({
      data: user.uid,
      provider: "custom"
    });
  }
});
```

Is the node.js server serving web pages? Can the clients contact Firebase directly? Sending the custom token to the client for its own use would be a more normal workflow:

```
function (request, response) {
    var token = createTokenForUser(request.user);
    var script = ['<script>',
        'var token='+JSON.stringify(token)+';',
        'var ref= new Firebase(...);',
        'ref.authWithCustomToken(token, ...);',
        '</script>'].join("\n");
    response.end(script);
}
```

If you are really not interested in doing things the usual way, you can just use standard node tools like [request](https://github.com/request/request) to make calls to the [Firebase REST API](https://www.firebase.com/docs/rest/api/) with your custom token in the  `auth` query parameter, like so:

```
var request = require("request");
var token = createTokenForUser(...);
var uid = ...;

request({
    method: "POST",
    url: "https://cexample.firebaseio.com/users/"+uid,
    qs: {auth: token},
    body: {
        data: uid,
        provider: "custom"
    },
    json: true
});
```

Without the standard Firebase library it will be hard to react to changes. You will need to set the header `Accept: text/event-stream` and write handlers for `"data"` events and make sure to close connections when you are done with them so you don't run up your Firebase bill.

Comment: i do not want to move this logic to the client. the server should be in charge of this actions.

if i use a priviledged token for the server then i lose the role permissions firebase gives me for each authenticated user, since the auth variable in the permissions will always be of the server and not the client.
spawning a child for each connected user is very not efficient and is not a valid solution

Comment: If you have set up security rules specifying the users' roles and permissions, there is no need for a proxy. The users can fetch the data on their own. Please add the use case to your question as you've fallen in the [XY problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem/66378#66378) here.

Comment: To demonstrate how this is an XY problem, your question was how to authenticate as different users from your node script. This answer is the correct one for your question, although it solves X instead of Y.